# How to transform and stream large XML files to postgres ? Mediawiki dump postgres

Tags: python, xml, postgresql, xpath, mediawiki

I want to use postgres' full text search on the largest public natural language corpus available. I downloaded this [wikimedia dump stub](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20200201/enwiki-20200201-pages-articles-multistream14.xml-p7697599p7744799.bz2) of a few megs for the example, the target is to work further with [dumps around 70GB uncompressed](https://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20200201/). [Here is the xsd](https://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10.xsd). 
I know there are other [open parallel corpora](http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Moses.LinksToCorpora) easier to work with, I want to focus on wikimedia here.

This might seem like a duplicate, but I would like to investigate a simpler approach compared to the other proposals I found : [postgres mailing list and lo](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/5D5B211D-317B-4A62-B625-C2D28323DAFD%40gmx.net), [postgres mailing list and js](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CANtp6R%2B4mm9HmrcVbSCCE_k3gXeCgnbuoL7UjibZoZJwoehrcg%40mail.gmail.com#5896eb38c601dbcc00549726a9d5e07c), [here with pg_read_file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33211885/7359123), [here with nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34303681/7359123), [here with splitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862106/importing-an-xml-schema-into-postgres-to-automatically-create-a-table-and-then-p), [here with splitting + csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54109811/how-to-import-big-xml-file-10gb-into-postgresql)...

I would like to **preprocess** the **xml before entering postgres**, and **stream** it **with** the **copy** command. **BaseX** allows serialization of xml to csv/text with commandline and xpath. I already have some [stub xpath command](http://ix.io/2csC) within postgres.

The text tag in the XML encompasses huge text blobs, the wikipedia article contents in wikitext, and those are tricky to put into csv (quotes, double quotes, newlines + all the wikitext weird syntax) so I wonder about the format. I would ideally like a stream, thinking currently of :

```
basex [-xpath command] | psql -c 'COPY foo FROM stdin (format ??)'
```

Here is my **question** : can basex process the xml input, and output the transform in stream rather than in batch? If yes, what output format could I use to load into postgres?

I intend to eventually have the data stored in [the mediawiki postgresql schema (at the bottom of the link)](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Database_layout), but I will fiddle with a toy schema with no index, no trigger... first.
[The problem of wikitext remains, but that's another story](http://ix.io/2csA).

Comment: "I  intend to eventually have the data stored in the mediawiki postgresql schema".  There is a tool specifically for that, https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Importing_XML_dumps.

Comment: jjanes pretty outdated isn't it?

Comment: how about http://www.thaiopensource.com/trex/tutorial.html  @AIDoubt  -- not sure what jjanes is...